# Compiling kernel module Debian 7.9 xillybus

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, compiling

I'm having problems to compile XIllybus kernel module. 
As this [official guide](http://xillybus.com/downloads/doc/xillybus_getting_started_linux.pdf) explains

(on the top of page 8 of 25) I unpackaged the tar.gz file and compiled the kernel module by typing the *make* command in the proper path. When I compile the module with *make* command, I get the following error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/home/xillybus/module modules 
make: *** /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/build: No such file or directory. Stop.
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

*/lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/build* path does not exist. What does it mean? Should I have to install some kernel packet? www does not help me.

This [topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75558/ubuntu-make-fails-with-no-such-file-or-directory-lib-modules-3-4-0-build) faces a similar issue but with a different driver.

I got stuck at **Get kernel.org cp210x.c** of that topic because I need to download the appropriate version of Xillybus instead of cp210x.c.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the appropriate `linux-headers` package.

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I did it but does not help me